# Do Ambari users and groups link back to local users / groups on the cluster nodes?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

Confused about what Ambari users and groups are.

When looking at the docs and the Ambari UI (Admin/Users and Admin/Groups), I get the impression that users / groups created in this interface should appear across all nodes in the cluster, but this does not seem to be the case, eg...

```sh
[root@HW01 ~]# id <some user created in Ambari UI>
id: <some user created in Ambari UI>: no such user
Same situation for groups created in Ambari UI admin section.
```

Not sure I understand to use of the Ambari users and groups if they do not somehow have a link back to user and groups locally on the hosts. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: Look at your `hadoop.security.group.mapping` setting in the core-site.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, users and groups are maintained in the Ambari database, not by the OS.

Ambari has to separately be configured to support PAM or LDAP login roles

To configure these, you would use `ambari-server setup-pam` or `ambari-server setup-ldap` commands

I think newer versions of Ambari will create HDFS home directories for users, but that still doesn't mean those accounts are known to any datanode or namenode

Comment: So to be clear, are you saying that the "users" / "groups" created in Ambari admin UI are not related to, say, HDFS or YARN access (unless Ambari is set to integrate with PAM or LDAP), right?

Comment: That is correct. I've only setup LDAP and that is all I see in the Hortonworks docs, but I have found references elsewhere to PAM

Comment: For reference for others, here is more info on the question where I clarify some more context: http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/249761/view.html